# OSX - Google Chrome force quit. Can't re-open all my tabs

Tags: macos, google-chrome, tabs, session

I force quit Google Chrome on my Mac and when I reopened it won't give me the option to re-open all of my tabs. I've looked at other similar questions to this but the answers seem to jump right in into finding files and no explanation of where to find them.

One answer said to go to `Library` then `Application Support` and find some kind of session restore thing in there but there's no Chrome or Google folder in my `Application Support` folder? Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you say what version of OSX and Chrome you are using. Please refrain from using Chrome in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to manually recall them from the bottom right of the `New Tab` window (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

[image]

Mine gives me an option after I just force closed it of "2 Tabs", clicked it and they're restored.  This has worked for me for the past year on OSX, Ubuntu, and Windows - for what it is worth.

Comment: +1 for a universal answer. Since this post is an answer, I'll comment that Chrome has a History menu, if you remember what pages you visited, you can then use them as a last-ditch effort.